# NotificationListenerService UI Update

Tags: java, android

Using the following method I can show the toast. 
But I don't have access to the **sbn object** from inside the `mHandler.post(new Runnable() {  });` block.

**How do I achieve this functionality?**

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

static Handler mHandler;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        displayToast("Service Started NL");

    }

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your variable final.

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

static Handler mHandler;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        displayToast("Service Started NL");

    }

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(final StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: This did solve the problem. But i wonder what is the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

change the modifier of 'sbn' to final:

public void onNotificationPosted(final StatusBarNotification sbn) {